# Delphi 7 - Is it possible to get Call-Stack Information outside an exception?

Tags: delphi, stack-trace

I'm currently trying to implement a Error/Bug-Report function in our Software that sends an E-Mail to our support-address.

I thought it would be helpful to get the Stack-Information at the time the User is notified of an error to see how he got there, akin to the Call-Stack-Trace in the IDE.

All the examples of getting a Stack Dump that I could find are from inside an Exception using tools like MadExcept or EurekaLog.

Usually we try to avoid try..except blocks though, we check values inside a function and display an Error with a custom MessageDlg(..) function if something is wrong.

I'd like to know if it is possible to obtain the Call-Stack Information outside an Exception and how I do that.

for example if the User clicks on a Button

```
procedure ButtonClick()
begin
  DoSomething(4);
end;

function DoSomething(SomeVal:Integer):Boolean;
begin
  if someVal>2 
  then result:=DoSomethingDifferent(someVal)
  else result:=ContinueWithXXX;
end;

function DoSomethingDifferent(errorVal:integer):Boolean;
begin
  if ErrorVal>3 then MessageDlg(......)
end;
```

I'd like to get the following Information:

```
1. ButtonClick()
2. DoSomething(4)
3. DoSomethingDifferent(4)
```

and attach it to the email.

Edit:
As of now, I am not using 3rd Party tools nor Software to get the call Stack as that would require to convince the higher ups to purchase a license first.
I wanted to know if getting a Dump of the call Stack is possible without such tools.

Comment: Well, which of the tools are you using, ME or Eureka?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that, I am using neither as of yet.
I gravitate towards ME but it will be hard to convince my boss to purchase a license, so I was wondering if it is possible to do without the use of 3rd Party tools.

I will update the question with additional Info

Comment: What you are trying to do is certainly possible with ME. I think you first of all need to choose a tool.

Comment: I have used JEDI libraries `TJclStackInfoList` for getting a call stack. But afaik there is no way to get parameters and values included, I might be wrong.

Comment: OK, the answer to your question is that it is possible to obtain a stack trace without a third party tool, but you'll need to write the code yourself.

Comment: After all they are written by someone...

Comment: At least madExcept offers a function _StackTrace_ described in this help page: http://help.madshi.net/madStackTraceUnit.htm#StackTrace